# Blast.js and create scrollintoview and opacity

Tags: javascript, blast.js

I'm a beginner, and a solid beginner in js. I'm trying to learn how to work with blast.js and took a sample of the animation. I need to make the animation start on `scrollintoview` instead of on `click` - how should I do it? 
Additionally - I need to figure out how to turn the opacity for each span 100%  at the end of the animation.

Help me deal with this. The questions are basic, but we all started with them.

```
    $(function() {

  $('#test').on('click', function () {
    // Blasts the title
    var words = $('h1').blast({
      delimiter: 'word'
    });

    words.each(function(i) {
      // Initialization of the position
      $(this).css({
        position: 'relative',
        top: 150,



      })

        .delay(i * 70)

        .animate({top: '50px'}, 400,); 


    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just trying to figure out how to trigger code (your blast.js code) when a specific element is in view (instead of doing it on click). Here's an example using `getBoundingClientRect` which is a useful function for determining such a thing:

(Scroll the code snippet until the yellow footer comes into view. This will trigger console.log messages showing you where you should execute your code)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
 const footer = document.getElementById('footer');
  const isInView = isScrolledIntoView(footer);
  if (isInView) {
  console.log('the element is in view and should now execute your code');
   // TODO: Run Blast.js code here...
  } else {
  console.log('the element is out of view and shouldnt execute your code');
    // TODO: If element is not in view...
  }
})

function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const elemTop = rect.top;
    const elemBottom = rect.bottom;

    return elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
}
```

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 1000px 250px;
}
header {
    background: red;
  }
  main {
    background: pink;
  }
  footer {
    background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>When the Footer (yellow div) scroll in, the code should run</main>
  <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</section>
```

Comment: It really works! If you're not a wizard, I don't know who you are. I still have to deal with this code, but I'd like to ask you about a simpler thing that I can't do. How to make opacity for each span? To the appearance of span, its opacity was 100%?

I try, but my Javascript stops working. Things are basic, but even with this I need help